# ActiveRecord fetch loop into one statement — merge columns into one attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Currently my data structure includes `Appointment`s, which belong to `Contract`s. I need to access list of all contracts along with the contracts' appointments (appointments filtered by field_rep).

```
def index # ContractsController
    rep_name = # …
    render json: Contract.all.map { |c| c.as_json_with_appointments_for_rep(rep_name) }
end

# Contract.rb
def as_json_with_appointments_for_rep(rep_name)
    appts = Appointment.where("contract_id=#{ self.id } AND rep_name='#{ rep_name }'")
    self.as_json.merge({ appointments: appts })
end
def as_json(options = {})
    super(except: [:created_at, :updated_at, :user_id]).merge({ dropoff_date: self.dropoff_date, items: self.active_items, user: self.user })
end
```

Here, every contract requires a separate database call to get its appointments, resulting in horrible response times.

I'm thinking I'll `INNER JOIN` `appointments` and `contracts` on `Appointments.contract_id = Contracts.id` but I'm not sure how to bundle the `Appointment` results into a nested hash in the result. Current output looks like

```
[ // List of contracts
  {
    'id': 1,
    'appointments': [
      {
        'id': 1,
        // … other appointment fields
      },
      // … More appointments
    ]
  },
  // … More contracts
]
```

The client is built to handle a contract with no appointments (if a contract has no appointments assigned to the provided rep). Currently using PostgreSQL on Heroku

Comment: rep_name sounds like it is probably a string... can it really be trusted to be unique?

Comment: It is, but reps will only be managed by one admin and there's no danger if they happen to be not unique (no data corruption or sensitive data being exposed)…for the use case, the system works :)

Comment: what are you expecting the output to look like?

Comment: also, try including appointments with your Contract.all call in the controller, it should cut down on the number of queries as it will then pull all appointments when it fetches each contract

Comment: Expected output is in the second code block. What would it look like to include appointments with Contract.all? That might be the solution I'm looking for

Comment: ah I thought that was the current output (you can imagine my confusion) also see xlembouras' answer, it's what I was about to say (though perhaps not as eloquently)

Comment: It is the current output — don't want the output to change, as there are clients depending on its format. Want to change the backend code to make it faster. @xlembouras' answer is close — just need to integrate the conditional on appointments somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to to use an `outer join`. Rails implements this with `includes` or `eager_load`.

In your case you can have

```
@contracts = Contract.a_desired_scope.includes(:appointments)
```

then

```
@contracts.to_json
```

will only require one query to fetch all contracts with their relevant appointments.

instead of `to_json` you can use whatever iterating method you want, without affecting the number of queries.

In your case you can have a `to_json` method for each model

```
#apointment.rb

def to_json
  desired_attributes_hash.to_json
end
```

and

```
#contract.rb

def to_json
  {
   id: id
   apointments: apointments.map(&:to_json)
  }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. How would I integrate the conditional on the appointments when getting the appointment to do the processing in the database — or would you recommend filtering them out in Ruby?

Comment: Got it, along with help from here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations